# How to "Distribute Points on Faces" in Blender but not randomize them

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I use the geometry node *Distribute Points on Faces* but not have them randomized?

Comment: Hello, could you add an example of what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an example with a *Default Cube*:

[image]

Instead of using the node `Distribute Points on Faces`, which would result in a random distribution of points over all faces, I subdivide the mesh with `Subdivide Mesh` and convert the resulting faces into points. At these points you can then instantiate your objects.

---

If you also want to align the rotation of the instantiated objects to the normals of the surface, you would first have to capture them with `Capture Attribute`, and convert them to a rotation with `Align Euler to Vector` before instantiation:

[image]

---

An even simpler variant would be to convert the faces directly into points with the node `Dual Mesh`.

This eliminates the need to capture the normals and they can be used directly, since the normals are automatically interpolated to the new points when they are converted by `Dual Mesh`:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: Hi. This works. But I have a problem. My surface is surved and I want the instances to point as per the normals of the surface. I used *normal* node and *rotate euler* node but they don't have any effect.

Comment: @NewBlenderer I understand. Maybe the update will help you...

Comment: The 2nd part seems to be correct but idk why it is not working for me.

Comment: Edit: It Worked. I did not put the Euler rotate on Auto rather it was on Z axis. Thanks.

Comment: i remember i was able to align euler with normal without a Capture Attribute node. why do we need it? https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrJf.png

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie In this case, that's needed because after the conversion to points, there are no more faces from which to derive the normals. But thanks, I just came across a small error that has just been corrected (I had previously captured the normals in the domain *Points* by mistake, instead of *Faces*).

Comment: aaaahh now i understand this node! thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: https://twitter.com/higgsasxyz/status/1676946622734028801