# How to "Distribute Points on volume" in Blender but not randomize them

Tags: geometry-nodes

My question is similar to [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/273922/134294), but I'm having trouble 1) applying this to multiple faces on the default cube 2) with an [offset along the normal](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272769/how-to-offset-objects-in-relation-to-the-curve-using-geometry-nodes).

[image]

This gives the following. Only the cones on top of the image are in the correct orientation, I'm trying to get all the other faces to point outwards away from the cube.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to connect the attribute to the vector of the Align Euler to Vector, not to the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, silly problem, all the nodes are more or less correct, except (as mentioned in the comment)

> You need to connect the attribute to the vector of the Align Euler to Vector, not to the rotation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to change for this
[image]

And it works !

[image]